# Simplest implementation of `Comparable::compareTo`

Tags: java, comparable

For a `StockQuote` class implementing [`Comparable< StockQuote >`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) with a `when` property of type [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)…

```
public class StockQuote implements Comparable< StockQuote >
{
    private LocalDateTime when;
    …
}
```

…is the following implementation of [`Comparable::compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) sufficient?

```
@Override
public int compareTo ( StockQuote that )
{
    return this == that ? 0 : this.getWhen().compareTo( that.getWhen() );
}
```

First checks for object identity with `this == that`, declaring equality:

- if both references point to the same object, or
- if both are null.

If *not* identical, this code then casts `that` to the expected type, and extracts the `when` object from both. Then we return the result of calling the built-in [`LocalDateTime::compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#compareTo(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime)) method. If either `this` or `that` are null, but not both, a `NullPointerException` is thrown.

I have wondered about using [`Objects.compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#compare(T,T,java.util.Comparator)) or [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Per the Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)), `compareTo` should throw a `NullPointerException` if its argument is null.

> **Throws:** `NullPointerException` - if the specified object is null

The `==` check is a permissible optimization but not necessary. You could just defer to `LocalDate.compareTo()` and call it a day:

```
return this.getWhen().compareTo( that.getWhen() );
```

You could also ditch the getters and access `.when` directly.

```
return this.when.compareTo( that.when );
```